# dsnap.Data() returns nil if the document does not exist

Tags: api, go, google-cloud-firestore, go-gin

I have written a controller `GetUser` to get a particular user from Database(Firestore) on the basis of `id` I put in the query. If the user is not present in the database then it should give the message that `"User not found"`. But along with this message I am getting `nil` keyword also in response.

The response I am getting:

```
{
    "message": "User not found"
}null
```

When I hover on `dsnap.Data()` I get the information that

```
(firestore.DocumentSnapshot).Data on pkg.go.dev

Data returns the DocumentSnapshot's fields as a map. It is equivalent to

var m map[string]interface{}
d.DataTo(&m)
except that it returns nil if the document does not exist.
```

Controller:

```
func GetUser(c *gin.Context) {
    paramID := c.Params.ByName("id")
    ........
    ........
    ........
    dsnap, err := client.Collection("users").Doc(paramID).Get(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{
            "message": "User not found",
        })
    }
    m := dsnap.Data()
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H(m))

}
```

Firestore reference link: https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore@v1.6.1#DocumentSnapshot.Data

Can you guys please tell me how can I remove `nil` from the response?
Thank you.

Comment: Return from the function after writing the user not found response.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Limón Thank you so much. It is working for me. Problem solved. But can you please tell me what happened exactly after writing return?

Comment: After writing the user not found message to the response, the function continues on to write the JSON encoding of dsnap.Data() to the response.  In the case where the user is not not found, the nil return value is encoded to null and written to the response.  The return statement causes the function to return before writing the JSON encoding of dsnap.Data() to the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved now. I write `"return"` after the `User not found` response.